# Rust macros: What is the difference between braced and parenthesized macro bodies?

Tags: rust, macros

[Afaik](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html), macros in Rust are declared by the following syntax:

```
macro_rules! <name> {
    (<pattern>) => {
        <implementation>
    };
}
```

However I found a version where the body is enclosed in parenthesis instead of braces in [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/repeat.html):

```
macro_rules! <name> {
    (<pattern>) => (
        <implementation>
    )
}
```

Notice also the missing trailing semicolon. My best guess is that this has something to do with the tail recursion that this macro uses, but I what is the official difference between a macro body enclosed in parentheses vs one enclosed in braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branches in the `macro_rules` simply have to be separated by `;`. A trailing semicolon is optional there. In the [formal grammar](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) of `macro_rules`, this is described by

```
MacroRules :
   MacroRule ( ; MacroRule )* ;?
```

The syntax here is similar to a regex. The list of rules is at least one rule, followed by any number of semicolon-`MacroRule` pairs. All this is followed by an optional semicolon.

The choice of `()`, `{}` or `[]` actually doesn't matter at all here. All three are accepted ways to parse a [`DelimTokenTree`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html)

```
DelimTokenTree :
     ( TokenTree* )
   | [ TokenTree* ]
   | { TokenTree* }
```

This means that a `DelimTokenTree` will be parsed the same whether it's surrounded by `()`, `[]` or `{}`.

---

In particular, the macro you linked works the same with [all six combinations](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=999be7d5233d01f606c77027f1568979) of choice of brackets and trailing semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the definition of a macro between `(..)`, `[..]`, and `{..}`, see the [reference documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html). The syntax for the block on the right side of `=>` is *DelimTokenTree*. I would guess the motivation for having all three variants is to allow the pattern of your macro to contain any two types of braces.

The semicolon is optional, as you can see in the *MacroRules* syntax. You can even use `(..)` and `[..]` for the outer parts of the macro.

When you [invoke the macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html), you can also use these three flavors, but there are restrictions how you can use each one:

> When used as an item or a statement, the *MacroInvocationSemi* form is used where a semicolon is required at the end when not using curly braces.